# Saving generic input parameters of a method

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic method that can accept any amount of parametrs, while saving that input type for later. An example:

```
 const wrappingFunction = <A extends any[]>(innerFunction: (...args: A) => void, defaultParams: A) => {
        const applyFunction = (...args: A) => innerFunction(...args);
        const defaultValue = applyFunction(...defaultParams);
        return applyFunction;
    };
```

In this example, I want to be able to call this method with a method that takes parameters and default values like this:

```
const f1 = wrappingFunction(
    (a: string) => {
        return;
    },
    ["default"]
);
```

And also be able to call it with a parameter-less function and no default values like this:

```
const f2 = wrappingFunction(() => {
    return;
});
```

The problem is with making `f2` possible.

Comment: You mention generics but don't define any type variables, maybe that would be a good starting point? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: @johnsharpe I updated the question so it's better defined now, thanks for guiding me to asking the correct question

Comment: Why not give the trifling little empty array as the second argument? It seems to me it makes a lot of sense in the typescript world. It can be avoided if you really wanted it, but it makes your code a lot more complicated, and you won't really gain much by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a generic type `A` which represents the arguments of the function should solve this.

```
const wrappingFunction = <A extends any[]>(
  innerFunction: (...args: A) => void,
  ...defaultParams: A extends [] ? [] : [A]
) => {
  const applyFunction = (...args: A) => innerFunction(...args);
  const defaultValue = applyFunction(...defaultParams as any);
  return { applyFunction, defaultValue };
};

const f1 = wrappingFunction(
  (a: string) => {
    return;
  },
  ["default"]
);

const f2 = wrappingFunction(() => {
  return;
});
```

We can use a conditional type for `defaultParams` and make it a rest parameter. But this requires us to use `any` in the function implementation.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcUEswHMBiBXMYKdcGAXhgB4BBGAUwA8o6wATCGJMATwG0BdAHwAKAFAwYmMHQT5CxcAC4YwgHTqkCLBGXUAlOUEwAbiHSsANOJjrVrOgDMkeADZQACpqQBbHTFqMzGwcAjAA-DChyrzU-KIGZEYA3tagkLCoKC7cckQkYOQqtprauglGUjK5CmBqGloQegDcqeDQMPZOrlAAakgueHSFmdnV%20XV2js5unsi%20nBxc3M3WCHRQeAgFSZxoowR54BYdU919A0MAvi3XoqJp7Q4AjIWImZi4BzViEsJIytAEB9yjAUhIJGsNlsWhJLlYJLwAESdaZQRFxFb3NqwBwAJleyDQHzG4GEwhBYJgkM2YBuKyAA)

---

It would probably better to not use an array at all and just use the rest parameter.

```
const wrappingFunction = <A extends any[]>(
  innerFunction: (...args: A) => void,
  ...defaultParams: A
) => {
  const applyFunction = (...args: A) => innerFunction(...args);
  const defaultValue = applyFunction(...defaultParams);
  return { applyFunction, defaultValue };
};

const f1 = wrappingFunction(
  (a: string) => {
    return;
  },
  "default"
);

const f2 = wrappingFunction(() => {
  return;
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcUEswHMBiBXMYKdcGAXhgB4BBGAUwA8o6wATCGJMATwG0BdAHwAKAFAwYmMHQT5CxcAC4YwgHTqkCLBGXUAlOUEwAbiHSsANOJjrVrOgDMkeADZQACpqQBbHTGqiBmRGAN7WoJCwqCgu3HJEJGDkKraa2rpBRlIy8QpgahpaEHoA3OHg0DD2Tq5QAGpILnh0ydGxuYkFdo7Obp7IvqXWCHRQeAhJIZxo7QQJ4BZVPbUNTS0AvmWboqIRlQ4AjMmI0Zi4c3liEsJIytAIZ5kwYRISI2MTZRLrVhIARNVelA-oEyrsKrAHAAmY7INBnDrgYTCJ4vGDvcZgLZDIA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now applyFunction can't be used with 0 params

Comment: @Mickey - yes, but why should it be callable with 0 params? Whent the `innerFunction` expects 2 parameters, you should also call `applyFunction` with 2 parameters. Otherwise there will be a type error when `innerFunction` tries to use its arguments

Comment: I updated the question so it's better defined now, thanks for guiding me to asking the correct question